# Keep list item pressed

Tags: android

How I can set selected a certain items of a list when clicked?

Example from Google Maps App:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this help you
Method 1: get the current selected position

```
 OnItemClickListener listViewOnItemClick = new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position, long id) {
          mSelectedItem = position;
          mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
 };

And override the getView method of your adapter:

@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 final View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_list, null);

if (position == mSelectedItem) {
     // set your color
}

  return view;
```

}

```
Method 2:


first put this in your listview

android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
Then create xml files in drawable to control the diferent states
```

## @drawable/list_selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>
</selector>
```

## @drawable/list_item_bg_normal:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
  android:startColor="@color/list_background"
  android:endColor="@color/list_background"
  android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

## @drawable/list_item_bg_pressed:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="@color/list_background_pressed"
      android:endColor="@color/list_background_pressed"
      android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

In your ListView Selection :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) {
             view.setSelected(true);
             ...
         }
    }
```

Comment: With that only change the color, I also need to give the shading effect in edge like see in the picture.